# Any possible way to convert cyrillic encoding to latin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, internationalization

I'm struggling with QGIS showing certain layers for cities and other places in cyrillic writing (when the encoding is set to UTF-8) inside the attribute table. I'm wondering whether there's an encoding (or a plugin maybe) available to show that cyrillic writing directly into latin writing?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Are you sure the files are stored in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I am very certain that they are stored in UTF-8 format, which is why they are shown in their original form, which is cyrillic. This also applies for other non-latin writing, such as Greek or Georgian writing.

Comment: Oh you don't want to change the encoding, you want to change the cyrillic letters to latin ones?

Comment: Precisely. And all the other non-latin ones.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614622/transliterate-any-convertible-utf8-char-into-ascii-equivalent and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transliteration which makes the question off-topic here at GIS.SE.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is [transliterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) Cyrillic into English or other languages which use Latin Script. (Not to be confused with *translation*)

I did something like this a few years back, attempting to reproduce the Soviet Cartographic style. I needed to transliterate street names from English into Russian.

There's an [online tool here](http://stevemorse.org/russian/e2rbatch.html) which does the transliteration from English to Cyrillic. So in my case, "Princes Street" came up with several options like "Принсс Стрит, Принцс Стрит, Принцес Стрит, Принцэс Стрит ..."

[This site](http://translit.cc/) offers transliteration from Cyrillic to English.

I'm not aware of any APIs to do this, however, so this might only be viable to do manually for a small number of features.

If you use OpenStreetMap data, you can access [internationalised names](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Multilingual_names). So for places in Russia, the **name** tag will usually be in Cyrillic. But the **name:en** tag will be in English (and **name:fr** in French, **name:de** in German, and so on...). That might be a useful data source to find translations / transliterations of place names.

Comment: Thank you, that might be useful. I am indeed using OpenStreetMap data, however I download data that has already been extracted beforehand and is in "original" form, in other words it's not internationalised. Do you know of a way to download such data in internationalised version?

Comment: depends where you got the extract from, and in which format. e.g. Geofabrik Shapefiles have a limited subset of fields IIRC. Try QuickOSM plugin if it's a smallish area, or the Import OSM functionality, and the fields should be there. They might or might not be filled in, but that's another issue :)

Comment: Well, in the best possible scenario, I need all the existing places of a certain country, listed in internationalised form. Do you possibly know of a way of achieving that?